# (Somewhat) complicated database structure vs. simple — with null fields

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

I'm currently choosing between two different database designs. One **complicated** which **separates data** better then the more simple one. The more complicated design will require more **complex queries**, while the **simpler** one will have a couple of **`null` fields**.

Consider the examples below:

**Complicated:**

[image: Complicated]

**Simpler:**

[image: Simpler]

The above examples are for separating regular users and Facebook users (they will access the same data, eventually, but login differently). On the first example, the data is clearly separated. The second example is way simplier, but will have at least one `null` field per row. `facebookUserId` will be null if it's a normal user, while `username` and `password` will be null if it's a Facebook-user.

My question is: **what's prefered**? Pros/cons? Which one is easiest to maintain over time?

Comment: I am more concerned about why you are storing the session key in the user table.

Comment: @RedFilter Why not? It's generated upon login to authenticate the user, no matter if it's a Facebook-user or a regular one. Excuse me if I'm missing the point, table design isn't my expertise ;-).

Comment: What if the user wants to log in simultaneously from two different devices/browsers?

Comment: @RedFilter That will not be possible. This is for a desktop-application which will only allow one user to be signed in at a time. [think library client]

Comment: Warning bells are ringing loudly with the presence of two the very similar tables `facebookusers` and `normalusers`. What if you get a 3rd type? Or a 10th? There should be one user table with an attribute column to show the *type* of user. A user is a user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question.

This applies to any abstraction you might choose to implement, whether in code or database. Would you write a separate class for the Facebook user and the 'normal' user, or would you handle the two cases in a single class?

The first option is the more complicated. Why is it complicated? Because it's more extensible. You could easily include additional authentication methods (a table for Twitter IDs, for example), or extend the Facebook table to include... some other facebook specific information. You have extracted the information specific to each authentication method into its own table, allowing each to stand alone. This is great!

The trade off is that it will take more effort to query, it will take more effort to select and insert, and it's likely to be messier. You don't want a dozen tables for a dozen different authentication methods. And you don't really want two tables for two authentication methods unless you're getting some benefit from it. Are you going to need this flexibility? Authentication methods are all similar - they'll have a username and password. This abstraction lets you store more method-specific information, but does that information exist?

Second option is just the reverse the first. Easier, but how will you handle future authentication methods and what if you need to add some authentication method specific information?

Personally I'd try to evaluate how important this authentication component is to the system. Remember YAGNI - *you aren't gonna need it* - and don't overdesign. Unless you need that extensibility that the first option provides, go with the second. You can always extract it at a later date if necessary.

Comment: Great answer, you made many good points. Thanks a lot for your answer - truly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

First, what Kirk said.  It's a good summary of the likely consequences of each alternative design.  Second, it's worth knowing what others have done with the same problem.

The case you outline is known in ER modeling circles as "ER specialization".  ER specialization is just different wording for the concept of subclasses.  The diagrams you present are two different ways of implementing subclasses in SQL tables.  The first goes under the name "Class Table Inheritance".  The second goes under the name "Single Table Inheritance".

If you do go with Class table inheritance, you will want to apply yet another technique, that goes under the name "shared primary key".  In this technique, the id fields of facebookusers and normalusers will be copies of the id field from users.  This has several advantages.  It enforces the one-to-one nature of the relationship.  It saves an extra foreign key in the subclass tables.  It automatically provides the index needed to make the joins run faster.  And it allows a simple easy join to put specialized data and generalized data together.

You can look up "ER specialization", "single-table-inheritance", "class-table-inheritance", and "shared-primary-key" as tags here in SO. Or you can search for the same topics out on the web.  The first thing you will learn is what Kirk has summarized so well.  Beyond that, you'll learn how to use each of the techniques.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, very well explained.

Comment: I would think Kirk's answer would have been flagged as "right".  My answer, while valuable, merely adds some more details to what Kirk said.

Comment: I guess that's fair enough, I couldn't choose. Two great answers!

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the database you are using. For example Postgres has table inheritance that would be great for your example, have a look here: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-inheritance.html

Now if you do not have table inheritance you could still create views to simplify your queries, so the "complicated" example is a viable choice here.
Now if you have infinite time than I would go for the first one (for this one simple example and prefered with table inheritance).

However, this is making things more complicated and so will cost you more time to implement and maintain. If you have many table hierarchies like this it can also have a performance impact (as you have to join many tables). I once developed a database schema that made excessive use of such hierarchies (conceptually). We finally decided to keep the hierarchies conceptually but flatten the hierarchies in the implementation as it had gotten so complex that is was not maintainable anymore.

When you flatten the hierarchy you might consider not using `null` values, as this can also prove to make things a lot harder (alternatively you can use a `-1` or something).

Hope these thoughts help you!

Comment: That link (why NULL values should not be used) is bizarre and extremely misguided, imo.

Comment: I removed the link (as I understand what you mean). Next time I will read my references more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Warning bells are ringing loudly with the presence of two the very similar tables facebookusers and normalusers. What if you get a 3rd type? Or a 10th? This is insane,

There should be one user table with an attribute column to show the type of user. A user is a user.

Keep the data model as *simple* as you possibly can. Don't build it too much kung fu via data structure. Leave that for the application, which is far easier to alter than altering a database!

Comment: I understand how you're thinking with the user-type-flag, but where is this user-type unique data going to be stored, if not in a separate table? Thanks a lot for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

Let me dare suggest a third. You could introduce 1 (or 2) tables that will cater for extensibility. I personally try to avoid designs that will introduce (read: pollute) an entity model with non-uniformly applicable columns. Have the third table (after the fashion of the [EAV model](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2010/10/21/the-eav-data-model/)) contain a many-to-one relationship with your users table to cater for multiple/variable user related field.

I'm not sure what your current/short term needs are, but re-engineering your app to cater for maybe, twitter or linkedIn users might be painful. If you can abstract the content of the `facebookUserId` column into an attribute table like so

```
 user_attr{
 id PK
 user_id FK
 login_id
  }
```

Now, the above definition is ambiguous enough to handle your current needs. If done right, the EAV should look more like this :

```
 user_attr{
 id PK
 user_id FK
 login_id
 login_id_type FK
 login_id_status //simple boolean flag to set the validity of a given login
  }
```

Where `login_id_type` will be a foreign key to an attribute table listing the various login types you currently support. This gives you and your users flexibility in that your users can have multiple logins using different external services without you having to change much of your existing system